# How do I prevent delays when dragging objects with the touch screen on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, input, windows-phone-8, xna, windows-phone

I am making a game for Windows Phone 8 in C# and XNA. The game involves dragging objects around the screen. The update method uses the following code to move objects around.

```
//Check for input on the touchscreen
GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

//'selectedObject' is a variable of type 'GameObject' - It refers to the current object that is being moved
if (selectedObject == null)
{
    //The method checks which game object to use as the selected object if one is not already being moved
    foreach (GameObject gameObject in gameObjects)
    {
        //Check if the input is a dragging motion and that the user's input intersects with the objects hitbox
        if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.FreeDrag && gameObject.Hitbox.Contains((int)gesture.Position.X, (int)gesture.Position.Y))
        {
            //Make 'selectedObject' refer to the newly touched game object
            selectedObject = gameObject;

            //'selectedPosition' is a 'Vector2' that is used in the drawing method to draw the selected object at a specific point on the screen
            selectedPosition = gesture.Position;

            break;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    //If an object is currently being moved, update its position
    selectedPosition = gesture.Position;
}
```

The code successfully moves the correct objects and shows them being moved. However, the motion of the objects is noticeably delayed. If the user's finger moves upwards on the screen while dragging an object, the object takes a couple of seconds to catch up. The movement of the selected object does not slow down the other objects (they move around randomly and continue to do so at the same pace as before the user started interacting). How do I prevent this delay and show the selected object being moved in real time (i.e. When the user's finger moves in one direction, the object is shown to immediately follow as opposed to staying in place for a second and then repeating the action)?

Comment: Have you tried "gesture.GestureType == GestureType.TouchDown" or something? That might be your issue, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: `GestureType.TouchDown` doesn't appear as an option in the GestureType enum. Is there a specific reference that I need to include?

Comment: After take a quick look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touch.gesturetype.aspx I see that there isn't really a type similar to a TouchDown event. But like I said, I don't know if that is even your problem.